# Pass user uid to Firestore stream query in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, provider

1. Here I am using provider in main.dart to stream "itemsInUserDocument" data from a document.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
          StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot>.value(
          value: DatabaseService().itemsInUserDocument,      <--- (1) Providing here
          ),
          StreamProvider<User>.value(
          value: AuthProvider().user,
          ),
      ],
```

2. My **problem** is passing the userUID to the Stream query here. My document id's on Firestore is my userUID.

```
final userUID = "3SlUigYBgsNgzjU8a9GSimhAhuu1";            <-- (2) Need to pass to stream "userID' below??


class DatabaseService {

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> get itemsInUserDocument {

    final DocumentReference userData = Firestore.instance.collection('userdata').document(userUID);

    return userData.snapshots();
  }
}
```

3. Here I am using the list in down the widget tree.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userTaskDone = Provider.of<DocumentSnapshot>(context);

    List taskList = [];    <-- (3) Using the list here. 

    taskList = userTaskDone['tasks'].toList();

    print(taskList);
```

- It currently works and I am getting the streamed data in section (3) as is now, but I need to pass the Firebase user UID into the stream in section (2).
- I can get the user UID in a stateful widget with setState function but everything I have tried doesn't work or seems like I am duplicating things too much, I am trying to use Provider to manage state properly.
- I can get the userUID with provider as well, but you can only use it on a (context), where my notifier section (2) is only a class.
- PLEASE help me with a solution.

**EDIT:**

I have tried the edits and the result is as follow:

Getting this critical error from provider when I enter the screen where it used to work before these changes to main.dart.

[image]

Here is the full code for main.dart with edits as it is now:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      title: 'Sendr',
      home: MainScreen(),
      routes: {
        SplashPage.id: (context) => SplashPage(),
        LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        NavigatorScreen.id: (context) => NavigatorScreen(),
        CragSelectionScreen.id: (context) => CragSelectionScreen(),
        CragRoutesScreen.id: (context) => CragRoutesScreen(),
        RouteDetailScreen.id: (context) => RouteDetailScreen(),
        MapScreen.id: (context) => MapScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

///Authentication Logic
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthProvider().user,
      child: Consumer<User>(
        builder: (context, user, __) {
          if (user == null) {
            return LoginScreen();
          } else {
            return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                Provider<DatabaseService>.value(
                  value: DatabaseService(user.uid),
                ),
              ],
              child: NavigatorScreen(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Database Service:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  DatabaseService(this.uid);

  final String uid;

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> get itemsInUserDocument {
    final DocumentReference userData =
        Firestore.instance.collection('userdata').document(uid);
    return userData.snapshots();
  }
}
```

I have made no change to my step (3) where I am using it, is this where my problem might be now?

I am trying to do more research on this. Working through the provider docs. If I understand your suggestion correctly, we are streaming the User value from AuthProvider at the top, then consume the User value just below it then passing the user.uid value to the DatabaseService, which is used down the widget tree again. Looks like I am almost there from your help. If you don't mind, please let me know what you think of the provider error on the screen. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a `switchmap` from `rxdart` which listens to and maps a stream `T` to one of `S`.

```dart
Stream<S> switchMap<S>(Stream<S> Function(T value) mapper) =>
      transform(SwitchMapStreamTransformer<T, S>(mapper));
```

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/transformers.dart';

final userStream = AuthProvider().user;

final itemsStream = userStream.switchMap<DocumentSnapshot>(
  (user) {
    if (user == null) return Stream<DocumentSnapshot>.value(null);

    return itemsCollection.where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid).snapshots();
  },
);
```

```dart
StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot>.value(
  value: itemsStream,
),
```

Writing this off the cuff so it might be wrong.

## Edit

Another way would just be to place your items provider one level below your user. That way you can just regularly consume the user uid value.

```dart
return StreamProvider<User>.value(
  value: AuthProvider().user,
  child: Consumer<User>(
    builder: (_, user, __) {
      if (!user) {
        // Not logged in
      } else {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            Provider.value<DatabaseService>(
              value: DatabaseService(user.uid),
            ),
            // More services that rely on user.uid
          ],
          child: SizedBox(),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

## 2 Edit

```dart
class DatabaseService {
  DatabaseService(this.uid);

  final String uid;

  getData() {
    return MyCollection.where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no experience with rxdart, but I will look into it thank you for your answer. I thought there would be an easier way to just pass the users uid variable into the query from a global variable or something. I am struggling to understand why this is so difficult to do.

Comment: Yeah, your easiest bet would've been something like `ProxyStreamProvider` but that's not really a thing. See [this issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/120#issuecomment-501165716) for details

Comment: In short, my question is "How to provide userUID anywhere in your app?" - If someone can answer that, it would be very very helpful.

Comment: Added an alternative method. You don't necessarily need to use consumer. You could also use a `Builder` and then call `final user = Provider.of<User>(context)` in its builder method or anywhere below that part of the tree to retrieve that user

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions, beens sitting with this for days, and I want to give this one a go for sure. But I'm not sure how to implement. In my step (2), this is a separate file where the the "DatabaseService" class is where I need that uid variable, how would I use it in this file?

Comment: I hope my code above is clear, I can always try and add if it doesn't make sense, just wanted to show the necessary stuff. It's in the consumption where I cant access te user UID, because provider consumers can only be used in stateful builders/context widgets. I have nothing to build in my step 2, its where I keep my "business logic", as I understand it.

Comment: I am actually using  your suggestion of  final user = Provider.of<User>(context) in a Stateful widget down the widget tree for a profile page. There it works perfectly fine. But what to do inside my step 2 I don't know, there is no stateful widget. Feels like I am missing something stupid.

Comment: So in my second example, when you construct the Database service, you should initialize the instance with the argument of `user.uid` (as I've shown). That then lives on the object and you can call it whenever from your class methods. Technically, I think you don't want to use `Provider.value` but instead just `Provider` when you're initializing a class

Comment: Hi Nolence, please check my updated Edit from your suggestion above as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have worked having main.dart looking as below:

Main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthProvider().user,
      child: Consumer<User>(
        builder: (context, user, __) {
          if (user == null) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: ThemeData.dark(),
              title: 'Sendr',
              home: LoginScreen(),
            );
          } else {
            return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot>.value(
                  value: DatabaseService(user.uid).userRoutesDone,
                ),
              ],
              child: MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                theme: ThemeData.dark(),
                title: 'Sendr',
                home: NavigatorScreen(),
                routes: {
                  SplashPage.id: (context) => SplashPage(),
                  LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                  NavigatorScreen.id: (context) => NavigatorScreen(),
                  MapScreen.id: (context) => MapScreen(),
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

My Notifier:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  DatabaseService(this.uid);

  final String uid;

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> get itemsInUserDocument {
    final DocumentReference userData =
        Firestore.instance.collection('userdata').document(uid);
    return userData.snapshots();
  }
}
```

Where I used it down the widget tree:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userTaskDone = Provider.of<DocumentSnapshot>(context);

    List taskList = [];    <-- (3) Using the list here. 

    taskList = userTaskDone['tasks'].toList();

    print(taskList);
```