# multiprovider - pass value from first to second provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, provider

I am trying to setup a MultiProvider but I am struggling to figure out how to pass a value from one to the other. I have a list of data that has a userID in it, my app would previously make a StreamProvider for user info and then another for the list of data. This was fine as I could pass the user.uid to the data and then apply the filter. Something like this...

```
final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamProvider<List<UserLevelTwo>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).levelTwoSelector,
```

The problem was that I couldn't access the List throughout the app so after researching it looks like it is meant to be put before the MaterialApp with the other Provider. I have got this setup but only with manually passing the UID.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>.value(value: AuthService().user),
        StreamProvider<List<UserLevelTwo>>.value(value: DatabaseService(uid: 'rgDe5I0QgFfa123mIgxo8VQew9T2').levelTwoSelector),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
```

What I need help with is how do I pass the uid from the first provider into the second provider?

The second streamprovider calls my DB service which is as below:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  Query getLevelTwoSelectorData(){
    return Firestore.instance.collection('ULTs')
        .where("UserID", isEqualTo: uid)
        .where("D", isEqualTo: false)
        .orderBy("R", descending: true)
        .orderBy("Desc");
  }

  Stream<List<UserLevelTwo>> get levelTwoSelector {
    return getLevelTwoSelectorData().snapshots().map(_userLevelTwoListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: are you using Firebase? Also, can you show us your UserLevelTwo model code?

Comment: Hi, yes, I am using firebase... I have edited my original to put the UserLevelTwo info in... thanks!

Comment: you don't need to pass around the data. Just do this to get the id in any .dart page: final id=FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! but unfortunately I seem to be getting an error on the uid part... "The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'Future<FirebaseUser> Function()'."

Also, what would happen in this situation if there is no User currently logged in?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know what you did to change the type into a Future<FirebaseUser>. You could check if the FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser is null as well. This will tell you if the user is logged in or not. You will get an error if you are calling Fireb...currentUser.uid. (uid was called on null) would be the error. Just use and if statement to check if  Fireb...currentUser is not null and if its not then get the id

Comment: I imported firebase_auth.dart to my database.dart file, then I added the suggested code instead of my previous uid..

class DatabaseService {
  //final String uid;
  final id = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

As you can probably tell, I am new to flutter... sorry if I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I got this to work by using the same method described here [Pass user uid to Firestore stream query in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597869/pass-user-uid-to-firestore-stream-query-in-flutter?rq=1)

More or less it seems that you have one StreamProvider for the user info, then once that isn't null, you create a multiprovider for the list with the uid from the original provider.

Thanks again!